# ember.js how to set title of option for Ember.Select

Tags: ember.js

I am a starter of Ember and I try to use Ember.js(1.0.0.pre) in my app.

I am trying to set title for my Ember.Select's `options` to show tips when mouseover.
But, I can't find any information about the option's title in API.

Do I have to write a function myself to populate the `"title"` attribute?
Is there any way like `"optionLabelPath"` to bind `"title"` attribute for options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this we need to `reopen` the `Ember.SelectOption`

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/92eCW/2/) is the fiddle for the following example

```
MyApp = Ember.Application.create();

Ember.SelectOption.reopen({
  attributeBindings: ['title'],
  title: function() {
    var titlePath = this.getPath('parentView.optionTitlePath');
    return this.getPath(titlePath);
  }.property('parentView.optionTitlePath')
});

MyApp.selectArray = [{
    label: "A",
    id: "1",
    title: "for Apple"
  },
  {
    label: "B",
    id: "2",
    title: "for Ball"
  }];
```

**Handlebars**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" >
  {{view Ember.Select
     contentBinding="MyApp.selectArray"
     optionLabelPath="content.label"
     optionValuePath="content.id"
     optionClassPath="content.title"
  }}
</script>​
```

​

Comment: Great! it works.  And I find the information here .[link](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.0.0-pre.2/packages/ember-handlebars/lib/controls/select.js#L480)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simplest I could come up with:
http://jsfiddle.net/aK8JH/1/

**Template:**

```
{{view MyApp.Select contentBinding="content"}}
```

**View:**

```
MyApp.Select = Ember.Select.extend({
    attributeBindings: ['title'],
    title: 'myTitle'
});
```

Read this: http://emberjs.com/documentation/#toc_attribute-bindings-on-a-view

Comment: This will add title to the dropdown not the options

Answer (score 0):

Below is what I've got after observing source code in Ember:

```
Ember.SelectOption.reopen({
    attributeBindings: ['title'],

    init: function() {
        this.titlePathDidChange();
        this._super();
    },

    titlePathDidChange: function() {
        var titlePath = this.get('parentView.optionTitlePath');
        if (!titlePath) { return; }

        Ember.defineProperty(this, 'title', Ember.computed(function() {
            return this.get(titlePath);
        }).property(titlePath));
    }.observes('parentView.optionTitlePath')
});
```